# Keeping form data in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have an HTML form in Rails. Sometimes when the user submit data, my server will reject it because the data is not appropriate (say, the user types a non-number in a field where there's supposed to be only numbers.)

```
  <%= form_tag "myproject/win", :id => "win_form" do -%> 
    ...
    <label>
      Year 
      <%= text_field_tag "year", '', :size => 20 %> 
    </label>
    ...
    <%= submit_tag "Go!" %>
<% end -%>
```

In that case, my controller returns an error message

```
  @notice = "Year must be a number"
  return render action: "new"
```

But all the data that the user typed in disappears, and the user has to restart with a blank form. Is there a way to keep that data for the user?

Comment: Yes, but why are you paving your own way and coding the form manually like this instead of following convention?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure how I'm not following convention. I'm using the Rails tag `form_tag`, `text_field_tag`, etc. I'm quite new to Rails, so please be patient with my knowledge.

Comment: Why you use form_tag instead of form_for in your app?

Comment: Check out [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and save yourself the headache.

Comment: Yeah, like my predecessors said, follow the convention and get stuff for free (if this form is connected with some AR model, then use form_for)

Comment: @visnu @socjopata My form is a basic form, and it is not connected to any specific model. That is why I use `form_tag` instead of `form_for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine if you don't have a data store behind this, but you can still leverage ActiveModel to create an object that you can use to help build forms (or use the [reform gem](https://github.com/apotonick/reform)). If you *really* don't want to do that, despite the additional capabilities it affords you, you can just use what you have now, but *pay attention to the arguments*:

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag:

> `text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})`
>
> Creates a standard text field; use these text fields to input smaller chunks of text like a username or a search query.

Your code:

```
text_field_tag "year", '', :size => 20
```

So you're passing in `''` as the value, and asking us why the value is `''`. Perhaps what you really want is this:

```
text_field_tag "year", params[:year], :size => 20
```